# Can I override a property in c#? How?

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, polymorphism, overriding

I have this Base class:

```
abstract class Base
{
  public int x
  {
    get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
  }
}
```

And the following descendant:

```
class Derived : Base
{
  public int x
  {
    get { //Actual Implementaion }
  }
}
```

When I compile I get this warning saying Derived class's definition of `x` is gonna hide Base's version of it. Is is possible to override properties in c# like methods?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You need to use `virtual` keyword

```
abstract class Base
{
  // use virtual keyword
  public virtual int x
  {
    get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
  }
}
```

or define an abstract property:

```
abstract class Base
{
  // use abstract keyword
  public abstract int x { get; }
}
```

and use `override` keyword when in the child:

```
abstract class Derived : Base
{
  // use override keyword
  public override int x { get { ... } }
}
```

If you're NOT going to override, you can use `new` keyword on the method to hide the parent's definition.

```
abstract class Derived : Base
{
  // use new keyword
  public new int x { get { ... } }
}
```

Comment: While overriding, I forgot `{ get; }` and hence it was treated as a field and didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Make the base property abstract and override or use the new keyword in the derived class.

```
abstract class Base
{
  public abstract int x { get; }
}

class Derived : Base
{
  public override int x
  {
    get { //Actual Implementaion }
  }
}
```

Or

```
abstract class Base
{
  public int x { get; }
}

class Derived : Base
{
  public new int x
  {
    get { //Actual Implementaion }
  }
}
```

Comment: Or you could use virtual on the base class, as Jeffrey Zhao mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

Change property signature as shown below:

**Base class**

```
public virtual int x 
{ get { /* throw here*/ } }
```

**Derived class**

```
public override int x 
{ get { /*overriden logic*/ } }
```

If you do not need any implementation in Base class just use abstract property.

**Base:**

```
public abstract int x { get; }
```

**Derived:**

```
public override int x { ... }
```

I would suggest you using `abstract` property rather than trhowing NotImplemented exception in getter, `abstact` modifier will force all derived classes to implement this property so you'll end up with compile-time safe solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
abstract class Base
{

  public virtual int x
  {
    get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
  }
}
```

or

```
abstract class Base
{
  // use abstract keyword
  public abstract int x
  {
    get;
  }
}
```

In both case you have to write in the derived class

```
public override int x
  {
    get { your code here... }
  }
```

difference between the two is that with abstract you force the derived class to implement something, and with virtaul you can provide a default behavior that the deriver can use as is, or change.

Answer (score 3):

```
abstract class Base 
{ 
  // use abstract keyword 
  public virtual int x 
  { 
    get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } 
  } 
}
```