# Shall the attribute properties be virtual?

Tags: c#, attributes, virtual

At [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84c42s56(v=vs.110).aspx#cpconcustomattributeexample) an example to write a custom attribute shows the following strange behavior

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{ 
  public virtual string Name
  {
    get {return name;}
  }

  // Define Level property. 
  // This is a read-only attribute. 

  public virtual string Level
  {
    get {return level;}
  }

  // Define Reviewed property. 
  // This is a read/write attribute. 

  public virtual bool Reviewed
  {
    get {return reviewed;}
    set {reviewed = value;}
  }
}
```

Why all properties are virtual?

Comment: They are virtual as per any class with virtual methods / properties, so they can be overridden in a derived class. This in no way means a custom attribute must have virtual properties.

Comment: Not necessarily a duplicate, but your question is answered by reading [Can I override a property in c#? How?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447832/can-i-override-a-property-in-c-how).

Comment: @CodeCaster I believe the OS is confused due to the fact that the MSDN example only uses virtual properties for custom attributes, not about inheritance and overrides in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's section on the particular MSDN article that the OP mentioned that is about attribute "inheritance", i.e. if you have a class with a method that is virtual and is annotated with an attribute, and you add a subclass and override that method, will the subclass method have the attribute applied to it? That's what `[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false)]` is about in the *Inherited Property* section.

Specifically:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [MyAttribute]
    [YourAttribute]
    public virtual void MyMethod()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Where YourAttribute is configured with `AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false)]` and MyAttribute has the default configuration.

```
public class MyClass
{
    [MyAttribute]
    [YourAttribute]
    public virtual void MyMethod()
    {
        //...
    }
}

public class YourClass : MyClass
{
    // MyMethod will have MyAttribute but not YourAttribute. 
    public override void MyMethod()
    {
        //...
    }

}
```

The default value for *Inherited* is true.

So in short, those properties are virtual in the article to describe this feature.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that there is any specific reason to do so, because [Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx) work well with or without [virtual specifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx) on their properties or other members.

```
public string Name
{
    get {return name;}
}

// Define Level property. 
// This is a read-only attribute. 

public string Level
{
    get {return level;}
}

// Define Reviewed property. 
// This is a read/write attribute. 

public bool Reviewed
{
    get {return reviewed;}
    set {reviewed = value;}
}
```

Will work just as fine.

---

But you won't be able to [override these methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645767(v=vs.71).aspx) in derived attribute classes.

For example, this will work:

```
public class WithVirtualPropAttribute : Attribute
{
    public virtual String Prop {get; set;}
}

public class DerivedFromWithVirtualPropAttribute : WithVirtualPropAttribute 
{
    // Compiles ok
    public virtual String Prop {get{return "0"} set{}}
}
```

This won't:

```
public class WithoutVirtualPropAttribute : Attribute
{
    public virtual String Prop {get; set;}
}

public class DerivedFromWithoutVirtualPropAttribute : WithoutVirtualPropAttribute 
{
    // Compilation error !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    public virtual String Prop {get{return "0";} set{}}
}
```

It can be a [design decision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023378/design-advice-when-to-use-virtual-and-sealed-effectively) for some specific scenarios, but as overall there is no need do so.