# How to override the property

Tags: c#, xamarin

in base LocalStorage

```
 public class BaseStorageRepository<T> 
{
    protected string OneKey = null;
    protected string ListKey = null;

    public async Task UpdateAllAsync(List<T> data)
    {
        await BlobCache.LocalMachine.InsertObject(ListKey, data);
    }
}
```

in child

```
public class CompanyStorageRepository : BaseStorageRepository<Company>
{
    protected new string OneKey = "Company";
    protected new string ListKey = "CompaniesList";
}
```

When  execution in

```
UpdateAllAsync
```

then OneKey == null;
But why ?
After all, I redefined the property in the derived class

Comment: Please post the code where you call the function and how you are using it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8447832/993547

Comment: `new` hides the implementation. You are not deriving anything.

Comment: A) You didn't write properties; they are fields. B) To override a property (or a method) it must be `virtual`. You didn't override it; you 'hid' or 'shadowed' it.

Answer (score 7):

> After all, I redefined the property in the derived class

No, you *hid* the field (not property) in the derived class.  Effectively the derived class now has *two distinct* `OneKey` fields.  The base class code is still looking at the field from the base class, not the `new` one in the derived class.

Also note that fields can't be virtual or overridden.  You *could* set the field value in the derived class's constructor, though:

```
public class CompanyStorageRepository : BaseStorageRepository<Company>
{
    public CompanyStorageRepository()
    {
        OneKey = "Company";
        ListKey = "CompaniesList";
    }
}
```

A marginally better design would be to use *properties* instead of fields.  With properties, you can control (and detect) when a value is changed, and you can change how the value is stored without breaking the classes semi-public signature.