# C# Overide Variable

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding, parent-child, superclass

I have a fairly basic question that is probably obvious to most people:

Is this the best way to force a variable to be overridden when the class is inherited?

```
class foo
{
public abstract int nameOfInt{get; set; }
}

class bar:foo;
{

public bar()
{

override nameOfInt = 0x00;

}
}
```

Comment: it depends on your requirement.

Comment: My only requirement at this point is that that variable has to be overridden when ever the class 'foo' is inherited.

Sorry if I am missing something; I am fairly new to this...

Comment: Your code is syntactically incorrect

Comment: Then making it abstract forces a concrete descendant to implement it. Note that it isn't a variable, it is a property, as such your example of `bar` won't compile since it overrides a property and creates a field.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/326223/overriding-fields-or-properties-in-subclasses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to `force` implementation then `interface` is the way to go. It tells the inherited object that the `rules (methods, properties...) must be implemented`.

In case of `abstract` class we can give basic definitions on how the behavior should be, but we cannot instantiate from an `abstract`.

Coming to your code:

The `property` - `nameOfInt` is named `abstract` and it is not contained in an `abstract` class - which is wrong as per the specifications.

This is how you should go about with this:

```
abstract class foo
{
    public abstract int nameOfInt { get; set; }
}

class bar : foo
{
    public override int nameOfInt
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This can help to decide whether to use interface or abstract class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474249/abstract-classes-vs-interfaces

Answer (score -1):

We can't talk about overriding a proprety in inheritance, I suppose that you talk about method overriding in that case you can force it by making the parent class abstract or make the class inherit from an interface that contains the methods to be overriden.

Comment: Actually this is possible to override properties http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447832/can-i-override-a-property-in-c-how